# When is the const operator[] called and when is the non-const operator[] called?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have two *very* different behaviors for reads and writes. In the event of reads, I want to copy a buffer of a rather hard to extract data structure. On writes, I will just write unbuffered to the structure.

Up to now, I have been using operator[] to do access, so for the sake of polymorphism I'd like to continue doing so.

So my question is this: When a access is made, which version is called? My notion is that the const is called for reads, and the non-const for writes. In that case, this is a simple thing to implement. Otherwise, it may be more tricky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, you generally need to have `operator[]` return a proxy, and overload `operator=` and `operator T` (where `T` is the original type) for that proxy type. Then you can use `operator T` to handle reads, and `operator =` to handle writes.

Edit: the basic idea of a proxy is pretty simple: you return an instance of an object that acts in place of the original object. For the moment, this is going to have really *trivial* semantics (just read and write a char at a specified index in a vector); in your case, the logic inside of the `operator=` and (especially) `operator T` will apparently be more complex, but that has little or no effect on the basic structure.

```
#include <vector>

class X {
    std::vector<char> raw_data;

    class proxy { 
        X &parent;
        int index;   
    public:
        proxy(X &x, int i) : parent(x), index(i) {}

        operator char() const { return parent.raw_data[index]; }

        proxy &operator=(char d) { 
            parent.raw_data[index] = d; 
            return *this;
        }
    };
public:
    X() : raw_data(10) {}
    proxy operator[](int i) { return proxy(*this, i); }
};

#ifdef TEST

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    X x;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        x[i] = 'A' + i;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        std::cout << x[i] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

The overload resolution is based on the `this` parameter, that is - on the constness or lack of constness of the object You call the `operator[]` on.

Answer (score 0):

Since the behavior between reads and writes is so different, you might want to at least consider NOT overloading `operator[]` but instead making separate `read` and `write` methods.

To answer your question, it's based on the const-ness of the object upon which you're operating. It doesn't know what you're going to do with the result of the operator so it has only one thing to work with, the object on which you're calling the operator. If the object is non-const it will always call the non-const (write) version of your operator. You *can* get around this by `const_cast`ing const onto the object, but separate methods seems like a better approach.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what you're "assigning" to:

```
const type& x=X[i]
```

will call the const version of the function

```
type& x=X[i]
```

or

```
X[i]=x
```

will call the non const version.  And finally, a simple assignment

```
type x=X[i]
```

There's no real way to say that one's a "read" and the other's a "write".  Basically the const version will return a view into your data where updates are not reflected.  The non-consts version will return a view into your data where updates can be reflected but there's no semantics to provide a refresh after a write.